# Google cloud with wordpress instance unreachable after SSL install

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-app-engine, ssl, https

I'm using Apache 2.4.10(Debian 8) on Google Compute Engine with a Wordpress Install (click-to-deploy).

I used let's encrypt for SSL and got that to work yesterday. The site loaded fine using HTTPS at first, but now, the site yields a '*This site can’t be reached, example.com unexpectedly closed the connection.*'-error when I go to the domain.

Some of the behavior that might indicate the nature of the problem:

- http://example.com, yields a 404: 'The requested URL / was not found on this server'.
- http**s**://example.com yields 'this site can't be reached'.
- When I go to the Google App Engine settings and add my (verified) custom domain (which I hadn't done before and which had never been a problem) then http://example.com becomes a login page for phpmyadmin.
- The server and files are still accessible

Some of the things I have done leading up to the problem that might have caused it:

- I set up let's encrypt SSL and chose the option to always use HTTPS
- On the wordpress administration page (which I cannot access anymore), I replaced the IP-address with the domain.

Some of the things that I have tried to solve the issue:

- I contacted the domain registrar for help and they helped me set up the 'right' records (A records and some others) for the custom domain.
- Found an issue on stackoverflow that seemed similar:
  [Google Cloud Platform: Cannot get https (SSL) working on Wordpress Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075971/google-cloud-platform-cannot-get-https-ssl-working-on-wordpress-instance), but could not implement the answers.

I think my domain does not point to the right place anymore. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong, or how I could figure that out?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be mixing up App Engine with Compute Engine. Not quite the same thing. Which one is it?

Comment: Oh, I see. Looking more closely, it is a Compute Engine instance, but I have tried changing settings concerning the site through the App Engine menu which might have caused or aggravated my situation. 
Thank you for your help.