# How to activate https for the instance create in google cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to activate https for the instance create in google cloud Platform. The VM is of wordpress (bitnami-wordpresspro-5-3-0-linux-debian-9-x86-64). I followed steps from the links :
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress-pro/administration/enable-https-ssl-nginx/
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/wordpress-pro/administration/create-ssl-certificate-nginx/

but was of no help.

Thanks!! in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to deploy your wordpress using Google Compute Engine. And you have created and installed self signed SSL certificate. But you need to make sure

1. your instance has a public IP (or VPN if you want to keep it private) or it needs to be behind a load balancer (assuming you are using a web browser to verify)
2. you need to add sufficient firewall rules to allow ingress traffic, see this thread for reference: [Google Cloud Platform: Cannot get https (SSL) working on Wordpress Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075971/google-cloud-platform-cannot-get-https-ssl-working-on-wordpress-instance?rq=1)
3. you'll need to install ssl certificate. Having a load balancer would make it easier for you to install and manage ssl certificates

`gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates create [SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME] --domains [DOMAIN_1],[DOMAIN_2] --description [DESCRIPTION]`

Or you can use cloud console to manage certificate using this link:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates

Unless you have a specific reason to deploy wordpress on GCE, it will be easier for you to manage wordpress on Google App Engine or using marketplace:

see: https://cloud.google.com/wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll get back if I got struck at any point in the above mentioned steps.

Comment: out of interest why are you trying to install it on compute engine? Do you have a specific use case for this?